# How to use an object across winforms

Tags: winforms, c#-2.0

So i have a List of a custom object class so the code looks as follow

```
var itemList = new List<Item>();
```

so for my Item its really just a simple class it only inherits defaults, and only has 3 private fields called

```
private double Price;
private string @Url;
private string Name;
public double setPrice(string price)
{
    this.Price = price;
}
```

My question since one was answered on how to remove from lists is how can I access a created item object from a list and edit its fields from a separate windows form. 
I.E.

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
private void itemListBox_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (itemListBox.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var editor = new form2();
        editor.Show(); //creating a new winform 
    } 
}
```

How can I edit the item variable in the edit form. 
So if I went to the second form. How could I access the name property from an item in the collection?

Comment: Use `itemList.Remove(item)` to remove an item from the list. As for you second question, you can pass the list to the form's constructor OR have a public `List<Item>` property on that form OR eventually make the variable `public static` so it can be access from anywhere in the code, though that is generally not a good design unless you want to follow the Singleton pattern.

Comment: -1: Please check out MSDN topics on `List<>` like [List<T>.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) and [List<T>.RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) and update your question with more concrete problem you have about these methods. (Also please don't ask 2 question in single post).

Comment: Edited with clarity on second question

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reference to `Item`, you can just use [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx):

```
 itemList.Remove(someItem);
```

Or to remove the `Item` at a particular index, use [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx):

```
 itemList.RemoveAt(5);
```

Now, to access this `itemList` across different classes, make it a pulic static field or property:

```
public class MyForm {
    public static List<Item> ItemList;
}
```

And then reference it using the name of the class where it was defined:

```
MyForm.ItemList.Add(...);
```

Comment: +1: Useful links, probably not going to help OP... Most likely scenario is items shown by name in a list and removal need to happen by name - `Remove` will likely hit reference/value bahavior expectation mismatch due to missing `Equals` on the class...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov True, but i didn't really want to cover *all* possible ways to remove an item from the list, just the big ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an item from the list by calling itemList.Remove(item);

Not sure what your second question is asking.